# Como exportar dados para o MercadoLivre? [PHP/JSON]

Tags: php, json, api

Baixei a SDK do MercadoLivre: https://github.com/mercadolibre/php-sdk

Só que sinceramente não encontrei como fazer exportação de dados pra lá. Tanto no Gib quanto no próprio ML tem tutoriais de como ler produtos, categorias e tudo mais, mas nada relacionado a exportação.

Por exemplo, como consigo enviar o nome de uma categoria no meu banco pra ver se existe no ML e pegar a ID deles? Alguém tem uma ideia de por onde começar?

Tutorial ML: http://pmsapp.mercadolivre.com.br/jm/ml.faqs.framework.main.FaqsController?pageId=FAQ&faqId=11063&categId=promo&type=FAQ

Arquivo de categorias de carros da API: https://api.mercadolibre.com/categories/MLB1744

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois que a autenticação estiver feita tu precisa saber qual é o *endpoint* da API que tu vai precisar usar.

No teu caso é o *endpoint* de search (`https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLA/search`)

Então se tu quiser fazer uma busca de produto por categoria é só fazer:

```
https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLA/search?category=MLB1744
```

(Fonte: http://developers.mercadolibre.com/search-by-category/)

E checar a resposta da API, que vai ser uma listagem com 0 ou mais items, ou então um erro.

Qualquer coisa é só checar a [documentação](http://developers.mercadolibre.com).

Comment: Massa, pior que aí que enrolei... não sei o código da categoria no ML. Digamos que eu tenha um carro "Focus", com o `?q=Focus` ele retorna um produto específico... ou eu viajei total aqui :P

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa documentação (https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLA/search/#options)
E olha o resultado do que tu disse: (https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLA/search/?q=Focus)

Comment: Poxa, valeu! No fim, viajei mesmo, não cuidei a tag `filters`